# Solving least-squares: why ever use iterative descent methods over pseudoinverse?

Tags: matrices, inverse, least-squares

I recall doing an assignment in machine learning where we ran regression tests on a data set, both using our own implemented gradient descent program, and then using the (right) pseudoinverse technique. At least in that particular instance, the latter worked much faster and fit the data much better.

When solving $Ax = b$ via least squares, are there properties of the matrix A that would make the pseudoinverse technique not work? I assume this is the only reason one would resort to iterative techniques.

Comment: If $A$ is very large, you may not be able to compute the SVD in order to compute the pseudoinverse. In this case an iterative method like steepest descent is all you can work with. Steepest descent is usually not the best choice among iterative methods, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterative techniques can be faster if an approximate solution is known $O(n)$, vs finding the pseudoinverse which is a $O(n^3)$ process. Additionally, though SVD is a stable algorithm even for large $n$, the relative errors for small eigenvalues may be large.

Comment: How could the approximate solution be found in O(n) time? Simply evaluating $Ax$ for a given x is O(mn), and for a lot of applications such as measurement models, m > n.

Comment: @YoungMoney - if you already have the approximate solution, refining it, should involve only calculating the gradient.